# How can I assign a random name to all charts in excel?

Tags: excel, vba, charts

I have a lot of charts in excel which look similar but with different data ranges, however they also have the same chart names. This becomes a problem when I am linking these charts to Powerpoint!

Is there a way to assign a random name to all charts in my workbook?

Comment: What do you mean by random? e.g. `Chart1, Chart2, Chart3...` etc.

Comment: Yes, or anything similar as long as each chart has a different name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work for sheet-type Charts:

```
Sub dural()
    For Each Chart In ActiveWorkbook.Charts
        Chart.Name = "Chart" & CStr(Rnd())
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Gary's Student, this looks wonderful and exactly what I needed :)